# CSS: How is height of block-elements calculated?

Tags: css, height

I use a div-Element that holds some comments. I basically use jQuery to add more Comments like so:

```
$(myDiv).append(
 '<li>'
 + '<img width="32px" height="32px" src="mySource"/></a>'
 + '<p>' + myComment + '</p>'
 + '</li>'
);
```

The problem is, that it seems that the height of the whole div doesnt get updated properly! The height of the div increases while I add more comments, but not enough, so after some comments it tends to overflow.

How is the height of an element actually calculated?

Comment: How about posting the CSS for your DIV? And probably validate your markup too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the general question of "How is the height of an element calculated", some info can be found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_heights_and_margins

As you can see, it's a bit complicated.

Some excerpts:

> **Block-level non-replaced elements in normal flow when 'overflow' computes to 'visible'**
>
> This section also applies to block-level non-replaced elements in normal flow when 'overflow' does not compute to 'visible' but has been propagated to the viewport.
>
> [. . .]
>
> If 'height' is 'auto', the height depends on whether the element has any block-level children and whether it has padding or borders:
>
> If it only has inline-level children, the height is the distance between the top of the topmost line box and the bottom of the bottommost line box.
>
> If it has block-level children, the height is the distance between the top border-edge of the topmost block-level child box that does not have margins collapsed through it and the bottom border-edge of the bottommost block-level child box that does not have margins collapsed through it.
>
> [. . . ]
>
> Only children in the normal flow are taken into account (i.e., floating boxes and absolutely positioned boxes are ignored, and relatively positioned boxes are considered without their offset).
>
> [. . . ]
>
> **Block-level, non-replaced elements in normal flow when 'overflow' does not compute to 'visible' (except if the 'overflow' property's value has been propagated to the viewport).**
>
> If 'height' is 'auto', [the height depends on the element's descendants](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#root-height).

Answer (score 1):

Is this happening in all browsers or just one?  Height calculations differ subtly between browsers.

The first thing I look at when the page isn't rendering like I should is whether the HTML is valid.  In your code, you have a closing `</a>` tag with no opening one.  This type of mismatch is enough to throw several browsers off.

It's happened to me several times where the navigation buttons seem to be in a very different location all because somewhere in my content I forgot to close a `<div>` or I added an extra closing element somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Are you appending to a DIV or a UL? It should be a UL

Try this CSS

```
li{clear:both}
```