# Why the dimensions of li are bigger in height then the dimensions of the image that is wrapped by li ?

Tags: html, css

I am making a list of brochures with words, explaining what they are, displayed on top of the brochure images.
Everything is good.It's just that the image of a brochure for some reason is rendered smaller in height then the div that is positioned absolute on top of it. As you can see in jsfiddle the ul that has the text is set to height of 100%. Well for some reason the ul with text steps out of the height of image.  I want it to automatically set the same height as the image. There is no padding, no margin. I just can't seem to understand why it is doing this. Also as you can see the li that wraps the image is also render bigger in height then the image.Any help is appreciated, Thank You! 
CSS:

```
img{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#brochures > ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#brochures li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
#brochures ul li a{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}
#brochures > ul ul{
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);   
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="brochures">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#" >
             <img src="http://0.tqn.com/d/office/1/0/i/4/-/-/Publisher-2013.png" />
             <ul>Example Text</ul>
             </a>
         </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/W76pw/1/

Comment: Try removing the white space between the img and a tags. You have added an (although non-existent) break. This can sometimes throw unexpected issues when styling.

Comment: Any particular reason for using a nested UL instead of a DIV for the text? Surely it would be simpler and more robust - or am I being thick?

Comment: @JulianKnight actually, having straight text in a `<ul>` like that is invalid HTML, the only permitted content for a `<ul>` is zero or more `<li>`.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's why I asked, I thought I might be missing something clever ;)

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to `img` layout :

```
img {
   display:block;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/W76pw/3/)

Comment: Ohh wow! Thank You so much! Could you maybe explain why that actually works? Again thank you so much!

Comment: @TekHelpDotOrg : changing layout from default for img(similar to inline-block) to block forces browser to calculate elements size in another way. Details can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4342092/3444240).

Comment: @TekHelpDotOrg : Please, mark as answered, if my post solved your problem.