# HTML 5 Why overflow-y:scroll does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following javascript that appends a text every second to a `DOM` element as follows:

```
function read(a) {
// htmlEntities(a) returns a text
var attendedStud = htmlEntities(a);
var html = "";
html += "<b>" + htmlEntities(a) + "</b><br>";
$('#result').append(html);
}
```

For every second, this function read(a) will append `text` to the `<div id=result>` in the view:

```
<div>
    <button href="#" onclick="load()" @*type="button"*@ class="btn btn-default">
    <div id="result" style="overflow-y:scroll"></div>
    <br /><br />
    <video id="video" width="800" height="600"></video>
    <br />
</div>
```

I have set the styling for `<div id="result">` to `overflow-y:scroll` so that whenever the function `read(a)` appends a text, it will have a scrollbar if the `<div id="result">` overflows. However, it does not work and it keeps adding the text to the `<div>` without the `autoscroll` property. How should I do it?

Comment: `style="overflow-y:scroll"` is not sufficient. The container will grow with its content. You'll have to set a `max-height`, so the container stops growing eventually.

Comment: What @insertusernamehere said. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4342153/1114123) will provide you with some more info.

Answer (score 1):

Set a height to the div. then it will work.