# When I am floating my li list to the right it is center-aligning

Tags: html, css

My unordered list in the div which has `class='insidehead'` is center-aligning, even though I have floated it to the right. I am scratching my head but can't find what the problem is. Please help me. I am new in coding and web development. The html and css code are attached.

Please provide alternative solutions or what changes I should make to my code to make the 'upperhead' class list float to the right side.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.upperheader {
  background-color: #1f5e93;
  height: 35px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Lato, sans-serif';
  font-weight: 400;
}

.insideuphead {
  width: 90%;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.insideuphead a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.insideuphead ul li {
  float: right;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.header {
  height: 110px;
  color: #848484;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family;
  'Raleway';
}

.insidehead {
  width: 90%;
  height: 110px;
  line-height: 110px;
  background-color: black;
}

.insidehead a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #848484;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 110px;
}

.insidehead a:hover {
  color: #1f5e93;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #1f5e93;
}

.insidehead ul li {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='upperheader'>
    <div class='insideuphead'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">SEARCH</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HMN PROFILE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CAREERS</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>
  <div class='header'>
    <div class='insidehead'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">AWARDS & ACHIEVEMENTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OUT CLIENTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your `div.insideuphead` also has elements that are `float: right`, and those elements bleed out of it.**

So the list elements of `div.insidehead` can't go fully to the right because the space is already taken. You can highlight this behavior by removing elements from your upper menu: the elements of the lower menu move towards the right hand side.

Possible solutions (pick *one*):

- Make the upper header taller:

  ```
  .upperheader{
    /*...*/  
    height: 55px;
  }
  ```
- Hide the parts that overflow:

  ```
  .upperheader{
    /*...*/  
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  ```

Both solve the bleeding of the upper header's elements, and make your `.insidehead ul li` go to the right side of the page.

Comment: Thank you soo much that works. Can you tell me what bleed out is and how to avoid it.

Comment: You’re welcome! Please mark my answer as solution :) The « bleeding » occurs because by default, blocks are not stretched to include their floating children (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342092/css-how-is-height-of-block-elements-calculated) The floats were taller than their menu, so they would overflow, taking space outside of the container. Use the Web Inspector on your page, you will see it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be the

```
.insideuphead{
width: 90%;height:35px ; margin:0px auto;line-height:35px;
```

Try changing the width to `width: auto;` and seeing if that makes a difference. Basically because its only 90% the `.insideuphead` will only reach about two-thirds of the page. So when you float it right it may seem like its a bit too the right but mainly in the middle

Answer (score 0):

```
.upperheader {
  background-color: #1f5e93;
  display:block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Lato, sans-serif';
  font-weight: 400;
  width:100%;
  height:35px;
}

.insideuphead {
  height: 35px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  line-height: 35px;
  position:relative;
  float:right;
  text-align:right;
}

.insideuphead a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.insideuphead ul li {
  display:inline-block;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.header {
  height: 110px;
  color: #848484;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family;
  'Raleway';
  width:100%;
}

.insidehead {
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  line-height: 110px;
  background-color: black;
  text-align:right;
  float:right;
}
```

this fixed it for me.

setting parent div width vs setting child width. In this case setting `.upperhead` width.

also adding `text-align:right` `float:right;` to the correct childs.

removing `display` from certain childs.

https://jsfiddle.net/xzq8mvju/1/