# default height of block element

Tags: html

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>simple text</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hi everyone I have a question about default height for block elements. For example below I have simple paragraph with default font-size: 16px but height of this element is 18.52. I know there is line-height which included about 115-120% of font-size. But how to measure it exactly.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>simple text</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: How is height of block-elements calculated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342092/css-how-is-height-of-block-elements-calculated)

Comment: Note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a question about default height for block elements [...] I know there is line-height [...] But how to measure it exactly.

It might be unwise to work on the basis that *default heights* will be pixel-identical in all browsers, on all operating systems, on all devices.

Instead, you can explicitly declare your `line-height`.

---

### Declaring absolute `line-height` values:

You can declare an absolute `line-height` like `48px`:

```css
code {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 48px;
  background-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);
}
```

```html
<code>font-size: 24px; line-height: 48px;</code>
```

### Declaring relative `line-height` values:

Or you can declare a `line-height` relative to the `font-size` like `4`:

```css
code {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 4;
  background-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);
}
```

```html
<code>font-size: 24px; line-height: 4;</code>
```